# How to add graphics.h header file in gcc compiler?

Tags: ubuntu, c

I want to print a pixel on the screen using C language. When I write code and compile it shows

> graphics.h:No such file or directory

I found that gcc doesn't have the "graphics.h" header file.

How can I add graphics.h to the gcc compiler?

Comment: Try this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-graphics-h-c-library-gcc-compiler-linux/

Answer (score 0):

in your .c file

```
# include <whatever.h>
```

the `<` and `>` will by default search in `/usr/include` for the specified files, which is why "stdio.h" always just works because that is found in `/usr/include/`

in your .c file if you have

```
# include "whatever.h"
```

then it will only search in the current folder the .c file resides in at compile time to find *whatever.h*.  So if you did `# include "stdio.h"` you would get not found, but if you did `# include "/usr/include/stdio.h"` that would work and is equivalent to `# include <stdio.h>`.

use `gcc -I/path_to_wherever -L/path_to_wherever myprogram.c -o myprogram.x` to compile to let gcc know where else to look for your .h files with the `-I` option and for lib files (.a or .so)   with `-L`

when in doubt, use `-I` and `-L` to explicitly tell gcc where the .h file is.

also there's no space after `-I` or `-L` when providing the path.

with the above out of the way, you need to have `whatever-devel` package installed, in whatever folder, which then provides `graphics.h` and the accompanying shared object `libgraphics.so` or the static library `libgraphics.a`.  The compiled code to whatever function you use out of `graphics.h` will exist in either the accompanying .so or .a file that you need to also reference at compile time to create a working executable.

you don't add `graphics.h` to the compiler, it is an independent piece of code that you reference from yours... you tell gcc to compile your .c file and reference these supporting libraries i.e. graphics.h with -I and -L

your compile line will be something like

`gcc myprogram.h -o myprogram.x -I/path_to_graphics.h_location -L/path_to_graphics.so_location -lgraphics`

the lowercase `-l` will say link with whatever library, just like `-lm` is link with the math library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use graphics.h on Ubuntu platform you need to compile and install **libgraph**. It is the implementation of turbo c graphics API on Linux using SDL.

Follow bellow steps
[image]